# Bayesian Vs MLE regression - getting different results

Tags: r, regression, bayesian, bugs

I've set up a Bayesian regression model in WinBUGS to determine values for the unknown parameters (b1, b2, b3, b4) and intercept value (b0) in a linear regression model. The code is as follows:

```
model {
for (i in 1:(J-1)) {
  FC[i]       ~ dnorm(mu[i], tau)
  mu[i] <- b0 + b1*(Factor_b1[i]-mean_Factor_b1) + b2*(Factor_b2[i]-mean_Factor_b2) + b3*(Factor_b3[i]-mean_Factor_b3) + b4*(Factor_b4[i]-mean_Factor_b4) 
}

b0        ~ dflat()
b1         ~ dflat()
b2         ~ dflat()
b3         ~ dflat()
b4         ~ dflat()
tau         <- 1/sigma2
log(sigma2) <- 2*log.sigma
log.sigma    ~ dflat()
}

Inits:
list(b0 =0,b1 = 0, b2 =0, b3 = 0, b4 =0, log.sigma=0)

Data1

list(J = 20, FC = c(1.87315166256848, 1.87315166256848, 
1.87315166256848, 1.8708501655802, 1.8708501655802, 1.8708501655802, 
1.93248104062608, 1.93248104062608, 1.93248104062608, 1.93248104062608, 
1.80846914258265, 1.80846914258265, 1.80846914258265, 2.10555453929548, 
2.10555453929548, 2.10555453929548, 2.10555453929548, 2.10555453929548, 
2.12908503670568, 2.12908503670568), Factor_b1 = c(7.0057890192535, 
7.0057890192535, 7.0057890192535, 7.05012252026906, 7.05012252026906, 
7.05012252026906, 7.13329595489607, 7.13329595489607, 7.13329595489607, 
7.13329595489607, 7.13329595489607, 7.13329595489607, 7.13329595489607, 
7.11720550316434, 7.11720550316434, 7.11720550316434, 7.11720550316434, 
7.11720550316434, 7.14124512235049, 7.14124512235049), mean_Factor_b1 = 7.09846620316814, 
Factor_b2 = c(7.2211050981825, 7.2211050981825, 7.2211050981825, 
7.2211050981825, 7.2211050981825, 7.2211050981825, 7.2211050981825, 
7.2211050981825, 7.2211050981825, 7.2211050981825, 7.2211050981825, 
7.2211050981825, 7.2211050981825, 7.37650812632622, 7.37650812632622, 
7.37650812632622, 7.37650812632622, 7.37650812632622, 7.46565531013406, 
7.46565531013406), mean_Factor_b2 = 7.28441087641358, Factor_b3 = c(2.37954613413017, 
2.37954613413017, 2.37954613413017, 2.28238238567653, 2.28238238567653, 
2.28238238567653, 2.28238238567653, 2.28238238567653, 2.28238238567653, 
2.28238238567653, 2.28238238567653, 2.28238238567653, 2.28238238567653, 
2.33214389523559, 2.33214389523559, 2.33214389523559, 2.33214389523559, 
2.33214389523559, 2.33214389523559, 2.33214389523559), mean_Factor_b3 = 2.31437347629025, 
Factor_b4 = c(2.06686275947298, 2.06686275947298, 2.06686275947298, 
2.09186406167839, 2.09186406167839, 2.09186406167839, 2.10413415427021, 
2.10413415427021, 2.10413415427021, 2.10413415427021, 2.06686275947298, 
2.06686275947298, 2.06686275947298, 2.32238772029023, 2.32238772029023, 
2.32238772029023, 2.32238772029023, 2.32238772029023, 2.2082744135228, 
2.2082744135228), mean_Factor_b4 = 2.15608963937253)
```

This WinBUGS code returns the following outputs for the unknown intercept (b0) and parameter (b1, b2, b3, b4) values:

```
     node    mean    sd  MC error   2.5%    median  97.5%   start   sample
b0  1.957   0.009337    3.764E-5    1.939   1.957   1.976   1001    56000
b1  0.1068  0.3296  0.001438    -0.5529 0.1072  0.7615  1001    56000
b2  0.5977  0.2758  0.001068    0.05286 0.5967  1.147   1001    56000
b3  0.1892  0.4394  0.001825    -0.6871 0.1899  1.061   1001    56000
b4  0.5757  0.1886  7.423E-4    0.1986  0.5765  0.9472  1001    56000
```

MY PROBLEM: When I compare these Bayesian estimates with results from a linear MLE regression in R, I seem to be getting a different result for the intercept value (b0). The code for the R linear regression is as follows:

```
FC = c(1.87315166256848, 1.87315166256848, 1.87315166256848, 1.8708501655802, 1.8708501655802, 1.8708501655802, 1.93248104062608, 1.93248104062608, 1.93248104062608, 1.93248104062608, 1.80846914258265, 1.80846914258265, 1.80846914258265, 2.10555453929548, 2.10555453929548, 2.10555453929548, 2.10555453929548, 2.10555453929548, 2.12908503670568, 2.12908503670568)

b1 = c(7.0057890192535, 7.0057890192535, 7.0057890192535, 7.05012252026906, 7.05012252026906, 7.13329595489607, 7.13329595489607, 7.13329595489607, 7.13329595489607, 7.13329595489607, 7.13329595489607, 7.13329595489607, 7.11720550316434, 7.11720550316434, 7.11720550316434, 7.11720550316434,  7.11720550316434, 7.14124512235049, 7.14124512235049) 

b2 = c(7.2211050981825, 7.2211050981825, 7.2211050981825, 7.2211050981825, 7.2211050981825, 7.2211050981825, 7.2211050981825, 7.2211050981825, 7.2211050981825, 7.2211050981825, 7.2211050981825, 7.2211050981825, 7.2211050981825, 7.37650812632622, 7.37650812632622, 7.37650812632622, 7.37650812632622, 7.37650812632622, 7.46565531013406, 7.46565531013406)

b3 = c(2.37954613413017, 2.37954613413017, 2.37954613413017, 2.28238238567653, 2.28238238567653, 2.28238238567653, 2.28238238567653, 2.28238238567653, 2.28238238567653, 2.28238238567653, 2.28238238567653, 2.28238238567653, 2.28238238567653, 2.33214389523559, 2.33214389523559, 2.33214389523559, 2.33214389523559, 2.33214389523559, 2.33214389523559, 2.33214389523559) 

b4 = c(2.06686275947298, 2.06686275947298, 2.06686275947298, 2.09186406167839,       2.09186406167839, 2.09186406167839, 2.10413415427021, 2.10413415427021, 2.10413415427021, 2.10413415427021, 2.06686275947298, 2.06686275947298, 2.06686275947298, 2.32238772029023, 2.32238772029023, 2.32238772029023, 2.32238772029023, 2.32238772029023, 2.2082744135228, 2.2082744135228)

# ======================= Linear Model =======================


lmfit_Linear_Model_Test =lm(FC ~ (b1 + b2 + b3 + b4))

print (summary(lmfit_Linear_Model_Test))
```

And the results from this MLE regressions are as follows:

```
Call:
lm(formula = FC ~ (b1 + b2 + b3 + b4))

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.05837 -0.00823 -0.00044  0.01307  0.04593 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)   -5.247      2.305   -2.28   0.0379 * 
b1             0.105      0.298    0.35   0.7280   
b2             0.674      0.195    3.45   0.0035 **
b3             0.177      0.394    0.45   0.6599   
b4             0.529      0.141    3.75   0.0019 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 0.0359 on 15 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.931,  Adjusted R-squared: 0.913 
F-statistic: 50.8 on 4 and 15 DF,  p-value: 0.0000000153
```

SUMMARY: Why is the intercept value (b0) coming to -5.247 with the MLE model and 1.957 with the Bayesian model? Should they not be the same?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the Bayesian model you are subtracting something (mean_factor_b1, etc.) from each of the predictor variables.  But you are not doing the same thing in the call to `lm`.

Assuming that "mean_factor_b1" is the mean of the "b1" variable, etc. this means that the intercept in the Bayesian model represents the predicted value of FC when all the b variables are at their mean.  In the MLE (`lm`) model the intercept represents the predicted FC value when all the `b` variables are equal to 0 (which may or may not make sense).

If you want the intercepts to match then you need to have them mean the same thing, either subtract the means in the call to `lm` or don't subtract the means in the Bayesian model.

Comment: Greg - You are indeed correct and I owe you many thanks. I've just run the updated code and the intercept values came out to be the same.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Greg Snow's answer is the probable cause, and have given it a +1.

But, there are two other considerations:

1. Did the BUGS calculations properly converge? It may not have. Did you do any convergence diagnostics/plots? Did you try different initial values?
2. Note that the `lm` regression didn't have the most significant results, though the Intercept is significant at the 95% level.

Comment: Wayne, thanks for the response. The model was converging and I ruled that out but I'm interested to know what you mean when you say the lm regression didn't have the most significant results. Are you possibly referring to the F-statistic and/or t-values?

Comment: Yes, the t-values for b1 and b3 were low and for the intercept was sufficient but...

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Greg Snow, I was subtracting the means in the Bayesian Model and not doing so in the MLE model. When I edited the MLE model to subtract the means (and therefore compare like for like) the results for the unknown values came out to be the same.

For those interested, here is the updated MLE regression code:

```
FC = c(1.87315166256848, 1.87315166256848, 1.87315166256848, 1.8708501655802, 1.8708501655802, 1.8708501655802, 1.93248104062608, 1.93248104062608, 1.93248104062608, 1.93248104062608, 1.80846914258265, 1.80846914258265, 1.80846914258265, 2.10555453929548, 2.10555453929548, 2.10555453929548, 2.10555453929548, 2.10555453929548, 2.12908503670568, 2.12908503670568)

b1 = c(7.0057890192535, 7.0057890192535, 7.0057890192535, 7.05012252026906, 7.05012252026906, 7.05012252026906, 7.13329595489607, 7.13329595489607, 7.13329595489607, 7.13329595489607, 7.13329595489607, 7.13329595489607, 7.13329595489607, 7.11720550316434, 7.11720550316434, 7.11720550316434, 7.11720550316434, 7.11720550316434, 7.14124512235049, 7.14124512235049)

b2 = c(7.2211050981825, 7.2211050981825, 7.2211050981825, 7.2211050981825, 7.2211050981825, 7.2211050981825, 7.2211050981825, 7.2211050981825, 7.2211050981825, 7.2211050981825, 7.2211050981825, 7.2211050981825, 7.2211050981825, 7.37650812632622, 7.37650812632622, 7.37650812632622, 7.37650812632622, 7.37650812632622, 7.46565531013406, 7.46565531013406)

b3 = c(2.37954613413017, 2.37954613413017, 2.37954613413017, 2.28238238567653, 2.28238238567653, 2.28238238567653, 2.28238238567653, 2.28238238567653, 2.28238238567653, 2.28238238567653, 2.28238238567653, 2.28238238567653, 2.28238238567653, 2.33214389523559, 2.33214389523559, 2.33214389523559, 2.33214389523559, 2.33214389523559, 2.33214389523559, 2.33214389523559) 

b4 = c(2.06686275947298, 2.06686275947298, 2.06686275947298, 2.09186406167839, 2.09186406167839, 2.09186406167839, 2.10413415427021, 2.10413415427021, 2.10413415427021, 2.10413415427021, 2.06686275947298, 2.06686275947298, 2.06686275947298, 2.32238772029023, 2.32238772029023, 2.32238772029023, 2.32238772029023, 2.32238772029023, 2.2082744135228, 2.2082744135228)


mean_b1 = mean(b1)
mean_b2 = mean(b2)
mean_b3 = mean(b3)
mean_b4 = mean(b4)

b1 = b1 - mean_b1
b2 = b2 - mean_b2
b3 = b3 - mean_b3
b4 = b4 - mean_b4

lmfit_Linear_Model_Test =lm(FC ~ ((b1) +
                           (b2) +
                           (b3) +
                           (b4)))

print(summary(lmfit_Linear_Model_Test))
```

And the associated results:

```
Call:
lm(formula = FC ~ ((b1) + (b2) + (b3) + (b4)))

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.05837 -0.00823 -0.00044  0.01307  0.04593 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value            Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.95866    0.00803  243.82 <0.0000000000000002 ***
b1           0.10543    0.29752    0.35              0.7280    
b2           0.67364    0.19504    3.45              0.0035 ** 
b3           0.17702    0.39433    0.45              0.6599    
b4           0.52891    0.14109    3.75              0.0019 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 0.0359 on 15 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.931,  Adjusted R-squared: 0.913 
F-statistic: 50.8 on 4 and 15 DF,  p-value: 0.0000000153
```